# System.Json JsonValue ToString() and (string) cast difference

Tags: c#, .net

I'm wondering why there is a difference of values between ToString() and (string) cast?

Many similar questions are referring that only difference should be that you can't call `ToString()` on `null` value.

```
var json = "{\"someKey\":\"Hello world!\"}";
var jsonObject = System.Json.JsonObject.Parse(json);

Assert.AreEqual("Hello world!", (string)jsonObject["someKey"]);    //ok 
Assert.AreEqual("Hello world!", jsonObject["someKey"].ToString()); //not equal, actual value is "Hello world!" (with quotes in the string)
```

Comment: You can override [implicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit)/explicit conversion operator (in your case explicit I think) and [`ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method). Knowing that shouldn't make you wonder anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `System.Json.JsonObject.Parse` returns a `JsonValue` object, looking at the source code available here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Json/src/System/Json/JsonValue.cs

We can see that the method `ToString()` is implemented as follows:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    var sw = new StringWriter();
    Save(sw);
    return sw.ToString();
}

public virtual void Save(Stream stream)
{
    if (stream == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stream));
    }

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, s_encoding, 1024, true))
    {
        Save(writer);
    }
}
```

However, to support casting to string using `(string)` that class implements the following:

```
 public static implicit operator JsonValue(string value) => new JsonPrimitive(value);
```

And by looking at the implementation of `JsonPrimitive` available here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Json/src/System/Json/JsonPrimitive.cs

We can see there is a method that will format the string as follows:

```
internal string GetFormattedString()
{
    switch (JsonType)
    {
        case JsonType.String:
            if (_value is string || _value == null)
            {
                return (string)_value;
            }
            if (_value is char)
            {
                return _value.ToString();
            }
            throw new NotImplementedException(SR.Format(SR.NotImplemented_GetFormattedString, _value.GetType()));

        case JsonType.Number:
            string s = _value is float || _value is double ?
                ((IFormattable)_value).ToString("R", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo) : // Use "round-trip" format
                ((IFormattable)_value).ToString("G", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
            return s == "NaN" || s == "Infinity" || s == "-Infinity" ?
                "\"" + s + "\"" :
                s;

        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

That's the reason you are getting different results.

Answer (score 4):

The reason your Assert is failing is because the [`JsonValue.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/cc626559%28v%3Dvs.95%29) method is an override that returns a ***text based JSON string*** result whereas casting the value directly returns the underlying string value.

```
var test = new JsonPrimitive("test");
Console.WriteLine((string)test);    // test
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString()); // "test" - with quotes
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `System.Json.JsonObject` inherits from `System.Json.JsonValue`, and that class overrides `Object.ToString()` with its own implementation:

> **ToString** -    Saves (serializes) this JSON CLR type into text-based JSON. (Overrides Object.ToString().)

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/cc626526(v%3dvs.95)

And to properly serialize a string as JSON, quotes are needed.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/cc626553(v=vs.95)) the `ToString` method:

> Saves (serializes) this JSON CLR type into text-based JSON.

So it's overriding the behaviour of `Object.ToString()`.